# Send error message from webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

How do I get error message from webmethod, I want to initiate error. Also, I want different error messages for different occasions.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "betting.aspx/submitFunction",
            data: JSON.stringify({ results: jsonObj, edit: $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CreateOrEdit").val() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(arg) { //call successfull
                window.location = "bHistory.aspx";
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert("Error! You need to login, and try again");
                window.location = "login.aspx";
                //error occurred
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced that problem as well. the issue is that if you throw an exception from your web method, it gets wrapped, like so `"Message":"{your message}","StackTrace":"   at ...`

what I ended up doing was creating this js function to parse the returned exception.
it's pretty ugly, and I'd love to see if anyone's come up with anything better.

```
function getErrorMessage(e) {
    return e.responseText.substring(e.responseText.indexOf("\"Message\":\"") + "\"Message\":\"".length, e.responseText.indexOf("\",\"Stack"));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
error: function(msg, status) {
    if (status === "error") {
        var errorMessage = $.parseJSON(msg.responseText);
        alert(errorMessage.Message);
    }
}
```