# unable to get Message from responseText

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

Spring controller:

```
response.sendError(500, ErrorMessage.DataBaseInsertFailed);
```

my .jsp page

```
    complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
    var errorMessage = $.parseJSON(e.responseText);
        alert(errorMessage);

    }
```

If i do e.status, i get 500

and if i do e.resonseText I get entire text, however I wish to display my custom message 'Database failure due to ...' My alert statement does not even fire. if i do `alert(xhr)` that does not fire either.

The above is from this one in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646575/send-error-message-from-webmethod)

Looked this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and changed my signature to match the document

```
complete
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
```

Comment: And _does_ your Spring Controller actually return JSON formated data …?

Comment: This is interesting, `alert(e.responseText)` gives me a html formatted string and buried within the body is my custom message

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you're seeing is the server's error page because you're sending a 500 error response. Set the response status and write your JSON to the response like this:

```
((HttpServletResponse)response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
response.getWriter().write(ErrorMessage.DataBaseInsertFailed));
```

Then in your ajax call show the error using the error callback:

```
error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
}
```